# Como trocar a cor do texto do navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-layout

Como eu faço para trocar a cor do texto , já tentei adicionar textcolor no XML do menu e mas não funciona [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver o problema é simples vá a sua activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
android:background="@color/color_navigation_list_background"
app:itemIconTint="@color/color_selector_navigation_item"
app:itemTextColor="@color/color_selector_navigation_item"/>
```

e no campo app:itemTextColor você pode colocar a cor que está no colors.xml

```
app:itemTextColor="@color/color_selector_navigation_item"
```

ou

```
app:itemTextColor="#fff"
```

Comment: Amigo , é a cor do texto , não do fundo , eu consegui adicionando a linha

Comment: app:itemTextColor="@color/color_selector_navigation_item"

Comment: a foi mal kkkk confudi com uma outra postagem semelhante que tinha salvo pra responder, mas é isso ai pra alterar a cor do texto está logo abaixo assim como as cores dos icones também.

Comment: Eu vi kkk valeu

Comment: Corrigi a resposta :D